# Not able to login on web page using requests library of python

Tags: python, request

I am trying to login on edx website through script. For this i am using requests library of python. Here is the code

```
from requests import session

ID = 'example@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = '*********'


with session() as c:
     g = c.get('https://courses.edx.org/login/', allow_redirects=True)
     csrftoken = (g.headers['set-cookie']).split()[0][10:-1]
     login_data = dict(email=ID, password=PASSWORD, csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='/')
     a = c.post('https://courses.edx.org/login/', data=login_data, headers={'Referer':'https://courses.edx.org/login/'})
     response = c.get('https://courses.edx.org/dashboard')
     print response.url
```

But this code is not working. Output is

> https://courses.edx.org/accounts/login?next=/dashboard

When i run `a.content`. It is showing

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Please anyone help me out.

Comment: Can you print the response from the first post session to check if the login was successful. eg. `check = c.post('https://courses.edx.org/login/', data=payload)`  `print check.test`

Comment: Your link requires sign in. Check the API of that site. Do they require some specific headers first? Maybe they require you to get a csrf token first, then use that to POST your login form?

Comment: @ user3636636 login is not successful. because when i tried `a = c.post('https://courses.edx.org/login/', data=payload)` then `print a`. Output was `<response [403]>`

Comment: Yes, It has API documentation.

Comment: @bad_keypoints, there api allows oAuth 2.0 for authentication.

Comment: What should i do now?

Comment: Read their api docs. See how to do simple login/logout auth http requests. Once you're logged in, then you'll be able to do GETs on their pages for scraping but requiring an access token in the header that you'll get after you  are authorized by their OAuth api.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are splitting for CSRF token the wrong way

```
csrftoken = (g.headers['set-cookie']).split()[0][10:-1]
```

will obtain csrf token as 'essionid=csrfstring'. you have to remove 'sessionid' part too. So change that to

```
csrftoken = (g.headers['set-cookie']).split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
```

Use a python shell to verify that you are getting csrf token in the right way.

Its good to register your app with edx api if you want to pull formatted data from edx. Then you can use OAuth 2 mechanism to access api. This includes creating a `code` and exchanging that code for `access token`. Its like OAuth2  authentication provided by gmail and facebook . More info on how to create tokens is [here](http://edx-installing-configuring-and-running.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mobile.html#create-the-oauth-clients). A [demo](http://docs.openedxapi.apiary.io/) is also available

Comment: But i do not want to use API. I want to do web scrapping.

Comment: @rohinichaudhary if you want to scrape pages that require authentication, then you *will* have to do authentication using their API, whether it's OAuth or not.

Comment: @rohinichaudhary I have edited answer above. See if it solves your issues. You can also try web scrapers like python scrapy.

Comment: If you have changed code as given in the answer then csrf verification will pass. I tried your code and there is no csrf verification failure occured. It simply returns an html page. You can try `python twills` also.